# Property 'create' does not exist on type 'typeof Completions'

Tags: javascript, next.js, openai-api

I am trying to build something using ChatGPT and I have installed version 4.8.0 (which is the latest).

I am using NextJS.

Last month I built something with v3.something and it worked fine, but now I can't make this work.

Here is my code:

```js
import OpenAI from "openai";

const instructionMessage = {
    role: "system",
    content:
        "Some instructions",
};

const configuration = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const prompt = "Prompt";
const temperature = 0.7;
const response = await OpenAI.Chat.Completions.create({ //issue lies in this line
        model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        message: [instructionMessage, prompt],
        temperature,
        max_tokens: 1000,
    });
```

I followed every possible documentation (in [official docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai) they have almost the same example) and whatever I do it says "create is not a function". I tried lowercase also (uppercase is suggested by TS as you may have expected), but nothing is working. I am a bit desperate right now...

Do you have any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: According to the documentation you linked in your question, it should be `configuration.chat.completions.create()`.

Comment: OMG! I am blind! hahahah. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

If I was reading docs more carefully I would realise that the answer is this:

```js
const response = configuration.chat.completions.create({...})
```

Thanks @Pointy for the help.